# Using BCP Utility with Azure Active Directory Integrated

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, bcp, azure-synapse

I'm trying use the BCP Utility to load data into a Azure SQL Data Warehouse, I did the download in the link below;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017

But after install, when I'm in prompt and I check the version of my BCP, the version is 14.0 and I've install 15.0.

I want use the 15.0 version because I need use the command -G to autentication with Azure Active Directory Authentication.

Anyone had the same problem? Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Gustavo Gouveia.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but are you aware that BCP will be up to 100x slower than using Polybase to load your data? BCP is OK when there are only a few rows to be loaded to a table, but Polybase is the recommended solution for data ingestion because it is faster than BCP, and gets faster each time you increase your DWU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download BCP Utility from the same link with you. My system is Win10 and I choose the Download Microsoft Command Line Utilities 15.0 for SQL Server (x86).

After install completed, I run `BCP -V` command, I found that the version is not 15.0.
[image]

I also run `sqlcmd -?` command and get the same version.
[image]

Actually I haven't fount the download link of the 15.0 version from the offical site.

I don't know why this happens. I have sent an email to Azure and wait the answer.

Please wait for my update.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download Microsoft Command Line Utilities 15.0.x for SQL Server. For ([x64](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2043518))(size 2.4 MB) or for ([x86](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2043622)) (size 2.2 MB).

These downloads give you the bcp release number: 15.0. Build number: 15.0.1000.34. Release date: October 18, 2018

As you mentioned, this new BCP supports Azure AD authentication, including Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) support for SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Installed v15 but bcp -v returned v14.

This happens when you installed multiple versions of BCP.

I run `where bcp` to determine all versions of bcp.exe and uninstall/remove the older version.

This issue is mentioned in [bcp Utility remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

Comment: I had same issue and Daniel's answer helped me.   Further info from Microsoft: "depending on the order of values of the PATH environment variable, you might be using the earlier bcp client instead of the bcp 15.0 client"